# How to compute p-value for Goodman and Kruskal's lambda and tau

Tags: r, p-value, association-measure

How do I calculate p-values for Goodman and Kruskal's lambda and/or tau tests for association between categorical variables (measure improvement in predictability of the dependent variable given the value of the independent one based on modal probabilities [lambda] or marginal/conditional proportions [tau])? I know SPSS can do it, but I use R instead.

Comment: DescTools has a test for tau (and gamma) and produces a CI for lambda.

Comment: DescTools doesn't give p-values for some reason, I've tried. Thank you for your try, but you're right about this question beeing off topic, so I've moved it to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366888/how-to-compute-p-value-for-goodman-and-kruskal-tau-and-or-lambda-tests.

Comment: A question about how to compute p-values for measures based on those tests would be on topic here; (you can even mention that you're working in R). It's also possible to back p-values out via confidence intervals, though it could be somewhat tedious.

Comment: <huge smile> In that case, I rephrase my question: **how do I calculate p-values for Goodman and Kruskal's lambda and tau-tests** and is there a way to do so in R? I hear it's based on chi²-distribution approximation, but I have no clue as to the mathematics behind it. ;)

Comment: On confidence intervals: yes, I sometimes do that (depending on the matter at hand), and it's always good to keep the option. Classical R hypothesis-testing functions such as `chisq.test()`, `fisher.test()`, `wilcox.test()` or `gkgamma()` (the latter from the MESS package) return `htest`-type objects that include p-values, confidence intervals, degrees of freedom, parameters, intermediate stats, etc. I've been trying to find an equivalent for Goodman & Kruskal's lambda and/or tau, but so far I haven't. For instance, DescTools and GoodmanKruskal return only coefficients, no intervals or p-vals.

Comment: Oh `rapportools` seems to have a test of lambda

Comment: Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts: this will enable you to edit and comment on your post.

Comment: sorry for the delay, that other time I couldn't access the comment section because of the accounts thing and since then I haven't had access to the internet; I know of `rapportools`'s `lambda.test()` function, but I can't seem to get a p-value from it and none of the demos I've seen show how to do so. I hear the method for calculating lambda's p.value is Suich & Turek 2003 (DOI 10.1348/000711003321645377) and that of tau is Mielk & Berry 1985 (DOI 10.1177/0049124185013004005).

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a synthesis data for illustration:

```
A <- sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size=1000, replace = TRUE)
B <- sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"), size=1000, replace = TRUE)
table(A, B)
```

Then this is the table of A and B

```
    B
A    B1 B2 B3 B4
  A1 79 86 90 87
  A2 76 89 79 93
  A3 70 92 84 75
```

Now, you can get the p-value of the Goodman and Kruskal's lambda test

```
library(MESS)
gkgamma_test <- gkgamma(table(A, B))
gkgamma_test
```

This is what you will get:

```
Goodman-Kruskal's gamma for ordinal
    categorical data

data:  table(A, B)
Z = -0.35154, p-value = 0.7252
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.08784091  0.06112170
sample estimates:
Goodman-Kruskal's gamma 
             -0.0133596
```

You can also take only the p-value by using

```
gkgamma_test$p.value
```

then you will only have

```
[1] 0.7251808
```

NOTE: when using the `gkgamma` test like above, we assume that A and A are **ordinal** categorial.

In case A and B are **nomials**, use:

```
library(DescTools)
Lambda(table(A, B))
```

and the value for λ is (The value λ lies
between 0 and 1; values close to 1 correspond to a
strong association.)

```
[1] 0.01437815
```

Read more about the two comments from
https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DescTools/html/Lambda.html

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vcdExtra/versions/0.7-6/topics/GKgamma

[Measure of association - How to choose](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/8756479308317006#:%7E:text=The%20choice%20of%20the%20proper,association%20that%20can%20be%20used.)